# Is there a different way to call method on variables which have similar notation?

Tags: ruby

Imagine this:

```
x_1 = "this is my dog"
x_2 = "this is my house"
```

I know that if you want to get the length of these variables you need to use `.length`.

I wonder if there is a a different way to achieve that. These two variables have similar notation - only the last character is different.
I want to do something like that:

```
["1","2"].each do |end|
  puts (x_1 + end).length
end
```

This is wrong, I know but I think you get what I want to do.
Do you have any idea?

Comment: Whenever you are tempted to name variables `x_1`, `x_2` etc, it is a hint that you should probably want to use an `Array` or `Hash` instead.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a different way to call method on variables which have similar notation?

You don't call methods on variables. You call methods on *objects*. That is an extremely important distinction. Variables and objects are *fundamentally* different, and understanding *how* and *why* a thing and the name of a thing are not the same is extremely important, not just in Ruby but in programming (and even life) in general.

> I know that If you want to get the length of these variables you need to use '.length'.

You can't get the length of a variable. A variable doesn't have a "length". You can only get the length of an object, not a variable.

> I wonder if there is a a different way to achieve that.These two variables have similar notation - only the last character is different.

Yes, it is possible to dereference a variable using a name you dynamically construct using the [`Binding#local_variable_get`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Binding.html#method-i-local_variable_get) method:

```ruby
b = binding

%w[1 2].each do |suffix|
  puts b.local_variable_get(:"x_#{suffix}").length
end
```

However, doing something like this is almost always a sign for a wrong design.

If you have a series of variables with consecutive names, that is almost always some sort of sequential data structure wanting to come out, for example:

```ruby
xs = ['this is my dog', 'this is my house']

xs.each do |string|
  puts string.length
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I get right what you want but:

```rb
["1","2"].each do |number|
  puts binding.local_variable_get("x_#{number}").length
end
```

It will print next:

```
14
16
```